# Using multiple Should queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get docs that are similar to multiple "groups" but separately. Each group has it's own rules (terms).
When I try to use more than one Should query inside a "bool" I get items that are a mix of both Should's terms. 
I want to use 1 query total and not msearch for example.

Can someone please help me with that?

```
{
 "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "p_id": "123"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "p_id": "124"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cat": "1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cat": "2"
                    }
                  },

                  {
                    "term": {
                      "keys": "a"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "keys": "b"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cat": "6"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cat": "7"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "keys": "r"
                    }
                  },

                  {
                    "term": {
                      "keys": "u"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3
}
```

Comment: Please tell what do you mean by "a mix of both should's terms"? May you provide a few example documents and the desired output vs actual output? Do you want to distinguish which search result matched which `should` group? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a terms aggregation on multiple fields with scripting and add a top hits aggregation as a sub-aggregation. Be warned this will be pretty slow. Add this after the query/filter and adjust the size parameter as needed

```
 "aggs": {
    "Cat_and_Keys": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['cat'].values + doc['keys'].values"
      }, 
      "aggs":{ "separate_docs": {"top_hits":{"size":1 }} }
   }
 }
```